# Is there any unzip alternative option beside built-in unzip R function?

Tags: r, encoding, unzip

When unzipping files with `unzip()` function there is problem with characters encoding. For example: Wojew˘dztwa instead of Województwa, paästwo - państwo etc. So my question is - are there any other ways to unzip files or how to extract files with specified encoding?

[image: Example]

## edit - session info

[image: sessionInfo()]

Comment: @arvi1000 sessionInfo updated!

Comment: For future reference (since it's not a big deal here), code and data should, wherever possible, be posted as text rather than images.